# RoR Routes Error: From a link_to built URL, route appears in rake routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, link-to

routes.rb

```
resources :project_associations, :only => [:update]
```

rake routes

```
project_association PUT    /project_associations/:id(.:format)  {:action=>"update", :controller=>"project_associations"}
```

ERB

```
<%= link_to membership_command[:text], project_association_path(membership_command[:id], :command => membership_command[:command])%>
```

Resulting HTML

```
<a href="/project_associations/2011?command=suspend">Suspend</a>
```

Click result:
Routing Error
No route matches "/project_associations/2011"

I kicked the server, same result

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: +1 for kicking the server as part of your debug process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to the `link_to`: `:method => :put`.

So:

```
    <%= link_to membership_command[:text], project_association_path(membership_command[:id], :command => membership_command[:command]), :method => :put %>
```

Comment: I concur. <a> tags don't let you set the http method, all <a> tags will result in a GET. Luckily rails does magic to make them submit with whatever the correct verb is.